# Disable selected and previous date which is selected in start date with Date Picker in the other end DatePicker in React

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, datepicker, react-datepicker

`I want to disable previous selected start date and time in the End date field. I am using Kendo Library for Date Picker. I have two input field Start date and End Date. Whatever date is select in Start Date input, I want it can Disable in endDate field and user can select only next date onwards dates in the endDate field. I have tried startDate + 1 at mindate attribute but it is not working

Comment: Could you share some code?

Comment: <DateTimePicker
     
                formatPlaceholder={{
                  year: "YYYY",
                  month: "MM",
                  day: "DD",
                  hour: "h",
                  minute: "mm",
                }}
                name="closeDate"
                // min={minCloseDate}
                min={moment().toDate()}
                // min={disableDates()}
                value={closeDate ? new Date(closeDate) : null}
                onChange={(e) => {
                  setCloseDate(e.target.value);
                }}

Comment: As I'm new in this field so face the issue while write the code.  it is normal 2 date picker I have, one for start date and other for end date, I want disable selected date and previous date in end date date picker

Comment: Could you update your question with the component including states?

Comment: Thanx for your valuable response @RubenSmn. I appreciate you and that you are always to ready for help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been resolved with property min using moment() functionality as below :

min={moment(startDate).add(1,'days').toDate()}